# Add multiple Layers to audio recording with PyAudio

Tags: python, audio, recording, pyaudio

Im been experimenting with audio recording and playback using `pyaudio`.

I'm able to record a file but I need to be able to add layers on top of it.  What I'm trying to do is record a 10 second file then start playing.

While its playing I want to continue to record additional 10 sec layers and add them over top of the prior recording.

Is there a way to do this with Python?

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 2
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 3
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print(int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS))

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a module called "PyDub" which does this easily.

http://pydub.com/

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

track1 = AudioSegment.from_file(track1wav)
track2 = AudioSegment.from_file(track2wav)

combined = track1.overlay(track2)
print ("overlaying recording")
combined.export(track1wav, format='wav')
```